# Hide UIImage while performing a task inside UIButton DidTouch event

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func exportDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
    self.logoImg.alpha = 0.0

    let result = exporter.composeString(context: context)
    exporter.export(composedString: result)
    let activity = exporter.activityVC()

    logoImg.alpha = 1.0
    self.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to hide an `UIImage` while I am constructing a file for exporting. Running this doesn't work as expected, the alpha is set to `0.0` only at the end when the activity controller is presented.

Being a beginner I don't really understand why this is happening, why isn't the image hidden exactly when the button is pressed ?

How can I fix this ? Hide it when clicking button, and show it back when activity controller is presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are in your action handler `exportDidTouch`, this will block the main thread and you will not see any UI-Updates unless the action handler has finished.

So you have to do the following:

- set the alpha value to zero (in your handler)
- spawn your calculations asynchronically (e.g. in a global dispatch queue)
- once the calculation finished, update the UI in the main thread

For example like this:

```
@IBAction func exportDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
    self.logoImg.alpha = 0.0

    // Start a work item in an arbitrary (e.g. non-main) thread
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        let result = exporter.composeString(context: context)
        exporter.export(composedString: result)
        let activity = exporter.activityVC()

        // Update UI in main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            logoImg.alpha = 1.0
            self.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```